# Is it possible to pass argument via method reference?

Tags: java, java-8, argument-passing, method-reference

I have the following code line:

```
MyClass{
    Runnable job; 
    ...    
}
```

and inside one of the method:

```
this.job = myImporter::importProducts;
```

Now `importProducts` is method without arguments:

```
public void importProducts() {
        ...
}
```

But I need to add argument to this method now.

After adding new argument, line:

```
this.job = myImporter::importProducts;
```

became broken.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: What type is `this.job`? And how does `importProducts` look after the change?

Comment: `became broken?` You have a compiler error? How about sharing it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you provide example with actuall code which we could use to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to "bind" and argument directly to the method reference. In this case you can easily use lambda:

```
this.job = () -> myImporter.importProducts(myNewArgument);
```

Alternatively if it fits your situation consider leaving the zero-arguments `importProducts` method which just calls the one-argument `importProducts` with proper argument value:

```
public void importProducts() {
    importProducts(myNewArgument);
}

private void importProducts(Type arg) {
    ...
}
```

This way your method reference will work as before.